# Javascript .hide() and .show() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following html:

```
<div class="menu_tab row">
    <div class="active" rel="#tab1">Tab 1</div>
    <div rel="#tab2">Tab 2</div>
    <div rel="#tab3">Tab 3</div>
    <div rel="#tab4">Tab 4</div>
</div>
...
<div id="tab1" class="tab_content">...</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab_content">...</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tab_content">...</div>
<div id="tab4" class="tab_content">...</div>
```

And following javascript inside seperate js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $(".tab_content:first").show();
});

$(document).on('click', ".menu_tab div", function() {
    $(".menu_tab div").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
    $(activeTab).show();
});
```

I can click on the menu tab and the tab is changed. But the problem is when the app is first loaded, it displays all four tabs but when I click, it works correctly. So what I think is, this part of code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".tab_content").hide();
   $(".tab_content:first").show();
});
```

is not working. Can someone tell me why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have any `CSS` for this?

Comment: **[Your code works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/cj5p6ozk/)**

Comment: Really? But it displays all the tabs in first loading in my localhost. :(

Comment: @Yin, provide demonstration of your code failing, otherwise the question is off-topic because it's not reproducible.

Comment: create your code at [jsfiddle](https://www.jsfiddle.net) and show link here

Comment: Perhaps change this: $(".tab_content").hide(); to $(".menu_tab div").hide();

Comment: @Yin.. Check for any console errors or post any related `CSS`.. You could even try to reproduce the issue if possible..

Comment: your code works, test in jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/mkasf4kq/

Comment: @MohammadAkbari But I don't know why it doesn't work at my site. Anyway, I use CSS fix suggested by Madalin Icascu and it is working now! Thanks a lot for the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(".tab_content").hide();
var activeTab = $('.active').attr("rel");
$(activeTab).show();
```

or use css:

```
.tab_content {display:none;}
.tab_content:first-child {display:block;}
```

Comment: It does not fix. :(

Comment: you have the exact code in the click event so this should work, can you see any console errors, why not use css?

Comment: Oh yeah! I totally forgot about CSS! Thanks a lot! It is working now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `$(".tab_content:first").show();` to `$(".tab_content:first-child").show();`

Comment: There isn't any problem with that... **[It works in fact](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/cj5p6ozk/)**

Comment: It does not fix. :(

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao Well, there is a difference, :first-child can target multiple divs with first-child, so it may be an issue for the OP

Answer (score 0):

Its already working.  I found there is no problem.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <script charset="utf-8" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="menu_tab row">
            <div class="active" rel="#tab1">Tab 1</div>
            <div rel="#tab2">Tab 2</div>
            <div rel="#tab3">Tab 3</div>
            <div rel="#tab4">Tab 4</div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">... Tab 1 ...</div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">... Tab 2 ....</div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">... Tab 3 ...</div>
        <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">... Tab 4 ...</div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".tab_content").hide();
            $(".tab_content:first").show();
        });

        $(document).on('click', ".menu_tab div", function() {
            $(".menu_tab div").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".tab_content").hide();
            var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
            $(activeTab).show();
        });
    </script>
</html>
```